# Как работает память в js

Tags: javascript

1. Основной принцип памяти в js является принцип достижимости
2. Принцип достижимости - это всем объектам можно получить доступ по ссылке или цепочке ссылок из корня
3. Корень - это глобальная область видимости

Существует 2 упрощения - к доступу объектам по ссылкам

1. Если есть ссылка на объект из корня он существует
2. Наличие ссылки  в корне не означает что объект доступен

```js
var a = {};
var b = {};

a.s = b;
b.s = a;

a = b = null
```

1. Тоже самое распространяется и на объект переменных в замыканиях
2. Если есть ссылка на объект переменных он существует
3. Если нет ссылки он объект переменных он удаляется
4. Я правильно понял как работает память в js ?

Comment: Вы описали примитивную схему которая могла быть актуальна лет 10 назад. Все современные движки без проблем удалят ваши объекты. Ну и вообще в стандарте JS вряд ли что-то про это написано. Это детали реализации конкретных движков

Comment: @Alexey Ten  получается эта статья устарела ?https://learn.javascript.ru/memory-management

Comment: Так ссылку надо сразу прикладывать. Там написано гораздо больше, чем у вас.

Comment: @Alexey Ten  извините :((